# Normal to Lognormal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, lognormal-distribution

I am planning to teach a class on normal and lognormal distribution and I wanted to:

1. Generate a standard normally distributed random vector `(mu=0, sigma=1)`,
2. transform the vector to a non-standard vector `(mu=250000, sigma=0.1*mu)`, and
3. transform the same vector to a vector that follows a lognormal distribution.

However, I think I am missing something, the values of mean and standard deviation are very different. Here is my super-simple code in MATLAB:

```
% Number of variables
N = 100000;

% Step 1 - Generate random standard normal distributed E
E = randn(N,1);

% Step 2 - Transform to non-standard values
mu_E = 250000;
sigma_E = mu_E * 0.1;
E_non_standard = mu_E + E * sigma_E;

% Step 3 - Transform to lognormal
E_log_non_standard = mu_E + sigma_E * exp(E);

% Step 4 - Compare
figure
hist([E_non_standard E_log_non_standard],100)
legend('E - normal','E - lognormal')
```

I know I could generate lognormal values directly, but I want to prove the transformation in class.

## Update number 2

```
% Number of variables
N = 100000;

% Step 1 - Generate random standard normal distributed E
E = randn(N,1);

% Step 2 - Transform to non-standard values
mu_E = 250000;
sigma_E = mu_E * 0.1;
E_non_standard = mu_E + E * sigma_E;

% Step 3 - Transform to lognormal

%mu and sigma transform to normal mu and sigma
sigma_logE = (log((sigma_E/mu_E)^2+1))^0.5;
mu_logE = log(mu_E)-0.5*(sigma_logE)^2;

E_log_non_standard = exp (mu_logE + sigma_logE * E);

% Step 4 - Compare
figure
hist([E_non_standard E_log_non_standard],100)
legend('E - normal','E - lognormal')
```

Comment: What makes you think the mean and standard deviation *should* be the same here?

Comment: Dear Gung, I don't expect them to be the same, it just seems to me that the result I am getting is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Based in my interpretation of what I think you want, I think you want step 3 to be E_log_non_standard = exp(E_non_standard) , but only you know for sure what you're trying to do. Your step 3 code as written doesn't make sense mathematically, even though it is "valid" MATLAB code in the sense that it specifies a mathematical calculation allowed by MATLAB.

Comment: Your result isn't "wrong" *per se*--it's just not what you claimed it to be.  You are computing $\mu + \sigma\exp(X)$ for a standard normal variable $X$: that has a special kind of three-parameter lognormal distribution. To create a lognormal variable you need to compute $\exp(\mu+\sigma X)$ or, equivalently, $\exp(\mu)\exp(\sigma X)$. With your choice of $\mu$, the values will be enormous. Experiment first with values of $\mu$ in the range $[-5,5]$ and $\sigma$ in the range $[0,1]$ so you can understand better what's happening.

Comment: What I suggested is equivalent to what @whuber wrote in his comment immediately above, but my formulation makes use of $\mu + \sigma X$ having already been computed and stored as E_non_standard . whuber has added a lot of useful color commentary, though,

Comment: Note that in the lognormal, $\sigma$ is a shape parameter and $\mu$ is a parameter that determines the scale. A "nice" value of $\sigma$ to try for a lognormal - one that's clearly skew but not so skew as to obscure all the interesting detail (in say a histogram) is roughly in the range 0.25 to 0.75, give or take. Much below 0.2 and you can sometimes have trouble telling it's skew unless the sample is large. Go much above 0.8 and the mode will tend to be in the leftmost histogram bin (unless you use a lot of bins). $\sigma=0.5$ isn't a bad first case to look at

Comment: @Glen, Mark and WHuber: Great, I can feel that I am getting there, please, keep helping me figure this out. First of all, yes, I had a mistake in my code and actually I need to compute exp(μ+σX), as Mark first mentioned. But, I am still confused with one thing: mu and sigma that I had chosen to use is actually one of the material properties of steel. However, if I use these numbers I get enormous numbers, while, for the non-standard normal distribution, which I am comparing to the lognormal distribution, all the numbers make sense to me.

Comment: If I just use different units for the material properties, everything looks great. Is this relationship limited to certain values of mu and sigma?

Comment: I presume you're confusing $\mu$ and $\sigma$ with the mean and standard deviation of the lognormal. They're not. Indeed, as you've already been told in Eric's answer the mean of the lognormal is $e^{\mu+\frac12\sigma^2}$; I'll add that correspondingly the standard deviation is $e^{\mu+\frac12\sigma^2}\,\sqrt{e^{\sigma^2}-1}\,$.

Comment: You might benefit from reading the Wikipedia page about the distribution to pick up some basic facts.

Comment: I suspect you might be asking the same question that has been answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116644 -- take a look.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure the link you sent is what I need. I have just added a slight modification to my original code, named "Update number 2", which makes sense to me. Please, let me know if that sounds right to you too. In short, I modify σ and μ before I compute exp(μ+σX).

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.  Could you, in your post, explain the purpose of modifying $\mu$ and $\sigma$?  Better yet, could you describe the intended output with some precision?  *Exactly which* lognormal distribution do you wish to simulate?

Comment: @whuber As an Engineer by training I will make up a problem that I have to solve: Imagine that a person went to the lab and tested a material a decent amount of times and got a sample mean of 250000 and a sample standard deviation of 25000. Now the person wants to run a reliability analysis and need a random vector with 10000 variables; the person somehow knows that the variable follows a lognormal curve and the person only have available a code in his computer that generates standard normal random variables (RV).

Comment: @whuber So, how can this person generate a lognormal RV with sample mean of 250000 and a sample standard deviation of 25000 only using the code to generate standard normal RV that the person has available?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to compare a shifted log-normal R.V. with a normal R.V. by histograms and sample mean and sample variance.

If $X\sim LN(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $E(X) = e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2}$. We can see then, that if $Y \sim N(0,1)$, $E(\mu + \sigma e^Y) = \mu + \sigma e^{\frac{1}{2}}$. So if the means are to match, you'll need to modify the other tranformation accordingly.

I'm guessing that what you are after are equivalent ways of transforming random variables on different scales.

Try instead (R code):

```
n <- 100
mu <- 2
sigma <- 3
x <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
x_trans1 <- exp(mu + x*sigma)
x_trans2 <- exp(mu) * exp(x)^sigma

#compare
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
hist(x_trans1, x_trans2)
```

Comment: Dear Eric, thanks for helping me out. You totally understood my questions. I have implemented in my code the function "exp(mu + x*sigma)" and "exp(mu + x*sigma)" when I use it for my values (mu <- 250000 and sigma <- 25000), the results are very of. Would the function not be: mu + sigma*exp(x)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend to show by that transformation. What distribution do you have in mind? Is it possible that you are confused about the relationship between normal and lognormal? Note that, if X is normal, log(X) is NOT lognormal (or even well-defined).

Comment: and Glen: I think I can see what was doing wrong, sorry for asking such stupid questions. In order to close this discussion, do you agree that if I want to to compare a shifted log-normal R.V. with a normal R.V. by histograms and sample mean and sample variance I should do the following:

Comment: I posted the new code as Update number 2 above.